# IIS 8.5 on Windows 2012 R2 works fine for around a day, then all my sites go down and give 500 errors. How can I diagnose?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, web-server, http, 500-error

In just the last few days IIS 8.5 on my Windows 2012 R2 server started going down. Every 24 hours or so, the server stops shows my webpages when going to a URL, and instead shows HTTP 500 errors. My server has been running smoothly for a few years and this just started happening. I can't recall any major changes I've made to the system (although I did do a PHP reinstall recently).

This is happening with every site within my IIS setup (about 10 different domains).

A simple stop/restart of the IIS component (not the whole machine) gets everything up and running again.

How can I diagnose this problem so it stops happening? Any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: The actual 500 error page tells a lot. Besides, IIS log files and Windows event logs contain necessary information. That's already a lot for you to analyze right now.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to identify would be the sub status code. Open IIS logs and search for the exact time when the issue occurred. Logs will be in UTC. So make sure you do the math. Please share the sub status code and I can help you further.

Also, enabling Freb would be the best way to identify this issue. While enabling the rule, ensure that you capture only data related to 500 status code.

Freb will tell you exactly which module within the pipeline is responsible for the error.